# The meaning of "regular triplet"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

> Behind the mare was plainly audible the cadence of a swiftly trotting horse. “D’you hear anything?” said Guj. “No—nothing but the **regular triplet**,” said Hordene; and he lied when he answered.

This is from ["Sleipner", late "Thurinda"](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/sleipner-late-thurinda.htm) by Rudyard Kipling. What does "regular triplet" mean?

Answer (score 7):

When a horse *canters*, the hoof-beats make a distinctive 1-2-3-1-2-3... rhythm.

It is nearly impossible to understand much of this story without knowing a lot about horses and a lot about British-India.  I know only a little and so there is much that is unclear to me.
But there is magical element to this story - When Thurinda is being ridden, the hoof-beats of a second horse can be heard following.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a musical reference:

[Merriam-Webster *triplet*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triplet)

: a group of three musical notes or tones performed in the time of two of the same value

*regular* here would mean something that you usually hear from a trotting horse.

(How they do that with four legs, I don't know.)

Comment: "Regular" here means "happening at regular intervals" -- "irregular" is its opposite. As in "regular heartbeat".

Comment: @RosieF I disagree. If it were *just a **a** regular* triplet, it would mean the opposite of *irregular*. But, to my ear, *just **the** regular triplet* means *the ordinary or expected*.

Answer (score 2):

Although a horse's hooves **do** sometimes sound in groups of three, I've never heard them do a musical *triplet*.

When cantering I think the pattern is three quavers and a quaver rest, like the **tiddle-um**s in the "Lone Ranger" section of the William Tell overture (tiddle-um tiddle-um tiddle-um tum tum). So we hear three clops followed by a tiny silence.

If they were triplets there would be no silence: like Bibbidi-bobbidi-bibbidi-bobbidi but never a Boo.

I love Kipling but I wonder if his musical vocabulary may have let him down here.

Comment: I like your illustrative phrases.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty: Do people even _know_ the Lone Ranger and Bibbidi Bobbidy Boo these days? :-)

Comment: I remember the latter from a 45 rpm disc of colored plastic. I think the other side was *The Teddy-bears' Picnic*.